# How to parse this JSON Data in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

Here is the JSON Data I need to import into my JAVA Variables

```
{
  "world": {
    "-61,66": "1",
    "-62,66": "2"
  }
}
```

I have tried the standard tutorials however they all require a formatted JSON file in which the author is in control of. In this case I am not. 
To break this down it is for Minecraft plugin called FactionsUUID which stores the map chunks players claim for their faction into grid numbers chunks of x and z hence the "-61,66" where they align to "x,z" and the "1" and "2" aligns to the Faction ID reference in another JSON file which doesn't need cross indexed right now. I just need to be able in my code to separate the claims by the Faction ID.

The world is an object but I cannot get the items below to parse into an array.

```java
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main() {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {

            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                    "C:\\TestServer\\jar\\plugins\\Factions\\board.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

(LINE 59 from Error below)
JSONArray theworld = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("world");

           Iterator<String> iterator = theworld.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
                Main.logToFile("FTOP-> " + iterator.next());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

```
[14:51:16 WARN]: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at com.ljd.perditionfcore.events.FTOPScan.main(FTOPScan.java:59)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at com.ljd.perditionfcore.Main.onEnable(Main.java:35)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:332)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:404)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:313)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:272)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:726)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:556)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:143)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:619)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:582)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.aO(DedicatedServer.java:416)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:379)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:715)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:618)
[14:51:16 WARN]:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Your JSON has no array in it, so you can't convert it as one. (`{...}` denotes an object, `[...]` denotes an array).

Answer (score 5):

`jsonObject.get("world")` returns an object (`{ "-61,66": "1", "-62,66": "2" }`) so you might want iterate over the key set of the resulting object:

```java
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("-61,66", "1");
map.put("-62,66", "2");

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); // obj =  {"world":{"-61,66":"1","-62,66":"2"}}
obj.put("world", new JSONObject(map));

JSONObject worldObject = obj.getJSONObject("world");

Set<String> keySet = worldObject.keySet(); // keySet = [-61,66, -62,66]

System.out.println(worldObject.keySet());
for (String key : keySet) {
    System.out.println(worldObject.get(key)); // returns 1 and then 2
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Your data is invalid, make sure to check for data you can parse.

The problem is in this line of code:

`JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;`

What would work in your case is

`JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;`

Comment: The JSON does not contain an array. There are no `[` or `]` in the JSON.